# Query for group by rows but keeping the minimum date

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have the next table with data:

```
user     group     dt_action
-----    -----     ---------
John     salvage   2016-3-2
Dennis   fire      2016-1-1
Martha   fire      2016-12-23
John     rescue    2016-1-20
John     salvage   2017-1-26
Developer NULL     2016-5-6
Dennis   several   2016-4-29
Martha   fire      2003-1-1
```

My idea is to group by the category "group", counting the amount of gorups per each user, but on the datetime field, I want to keep the minim date of each group sumarized. The result should be something like that:

```
user      group   count_group     dt_action_min
----      -----   -----------    -------------
John      salvage     2           2016-3-2
John      rescue      1           2016-1-20
Dennis    fire        1           2016-1-1
Dennis    several     1           2016-4-29
Martha    fire        2           2003-1-1
Developer NULL        1           2016-5-6
```

This is a query that long time ago has stolen my dream, but I can get it!
Thanks a lot,

Dani

Comment: What did you try? What exactly gives you headache?

Comment: What you want to do is getting informaton not only per group, but per user and group. So you'll have to group by user and group. Then just use the count and min function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CREATE table/INSERT data**

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
    (`user` VARCHAR(9), `group` VARCHAR(7), `dt_action` VARCHAR(10))
;

INSERT INTO DATA
    (`user`, `group`, `dt_action`)
VALUES
    ('John', 'salvage', '2016-3-2'),
    ('Dennis', 'fire', '2016-1-1'),
    ('Martha', 'fire', '2016-12-23'),
    ('John', 'rescue', '2016-1-20'),
    ('John', 'salvage', '2017-1-26'),
    ('Developer', NULL, '2016-5-6'),
    ('Dennis', 'several', '2016-4-29'),
    ('Martha', 'fire', '2003-1-1')
;
```

**Query**

Replace data with your own table name

```
SELECT
    `data`.`user`
  , `data`.`group`
  , `data_group`.`count_group`
  , `data_group`.`min_dt_action`
FROM
 `data` 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
     `data`.user
   , `data`.`group` 
   , COUNT(*) count_group
   , MIN(`data`.`dt_action`) min_dt_action
  FROM 
   `data`
  GROUP BY
     `data`.user
   , `data`.`group` 
) data_group
ON
 `data`.`user` = data_group.`user`
AND
  `data`.dt_action = data_group.min_dt_action
ORDER BY 
 `data_group`.`count_group` DESC
```

**Result**

```
user       group    count_group  min_dt_action  
---------  -------  -----------  ---------------
Martha     fire               2  2003-1-1       
John       salvage            2  2016-3-2       
John       rescue             1  2016-1-20      
Developer  (NULL)             1  2016-5-6       
Dennis     fire               1  2016-1-1       
Dennis     several            1  2016-4-29
```

Comment: Perfect, @Rayomnd Niijland. Seems that works fine! The question I have is why the internal query  you called 'data_group' is not the only necessary to do that, due you're grouping by the minimum of the dt_action. Do you know why the minim date is not get when you use only the internal query?